# Extending Docker Container Size on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have Docker installed on my Amazon Linux Instance. Below are the details of the docker install. I am trying to increase the default container size and am having errors in doing so. I have added on "--storage-opt dm.basesize=100G" to my /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage file, but am unable to get docker running after that statement. In my research I think it may have something to do with the storage driver that it is using: overlay2. Any advice on how I can increase would be helpful.

**Docker Info**
[image]

**Docker Storage Options**

```
DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="--storage-opt dm.basesize=100G"
```

**Error when restarting Docker**

```
    [root@ip-172-31-35-212 sysconfig]# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2020-10-06 18:52:25 UTC; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 21254 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_ADD_RUNTIMES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: Try to put your setting into `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, like described [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/cannot-change-docker-size-on-ubuntu-16-04)  (link updated)

Comment: If it's using the `overlay2` storage driver, then it can use the entire system disk, and the options for the `devicemapper` storage driver (like `dm.basesize`) don't work.